# Listing all directories and files in a sub-directory not working - Python

Tags: python

I need to print a list of all files in sub-directories of the directory "H:\Reference_Archive\1EastRefsJan2014".  I am currently using the code:

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk("H:\Reference_Archive\1EastRefsJan2014"):
    for name in files:
        print os.path.join(root, name)
```

The code works and I get a long list of files if I run it only on the root directory ("H:\Reference_Archive"), but when I try to run it on the sub-directory as it is written above, nothing is returned or printed. The path that is written above contains several more sub-directories which all contain files.  I have double checked that I have the pathway correct.

Comment: Your assumption about what `os.walk` returns is wrong. Are you sure the code you posted runs?

Comment: Well, to start, each iteration of `os.walk` returns a triple: `root, dirs, files`

Comment: I am getting the same result when I include dirs.  It gives me a list of all files in all sub-directories if I only include the root path, but gives me nothing if I include the sub-directory that I would like to view.

Answer (score 0):

try this, you omitted dirs

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk("H:\Reference_Archive\1EastRefsJan2014"):
    for name in files:
        print os.path.join(root, name)
```

Comment: I am getting the same result when I include dirs.  It gives me a list of all files in all sub-directories if I only include the root path, but gives me nothing if I include the sub-directory that I would like to access.

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured out that the os.walk function was not working with my folder because the folder name started with a number.  Once I changed the name of the folder, it worked properly.